# Full abstract factory pattern to use for Code Igniter models

Tags: php, codeigniter, design-patterns, codeigniter-2, abstract-factory

I’m creating a website where I’m using MongoDB as database, buy I also want to be able to use any other storage system in the future, so I would like to use a full implementation of the abstract factory pattern. With a full implementation I refer to this:

- “Database_factory” abstract class, which should be use by the client code (controller) to create a factory object.
- “Mongodb_factory” class, which extends Database_factory class.
- “Customers” abstract class that represents a set of queries.
- “Mongodb_customers” class that implements “Customers” class. “Mongodb_customers” object should be returned by the “Mongodb_factory”.

I know exactly how to do this with pure OO PHP. But I don’t know how to merge it with the models arquitecture that CodeIgniter provides.

It would be easy to just have the “Customers” abstract class and then the “Mongodb_customers” to implement it, but I want to make use of the factories too.

When you need a model in CodeIgniter, you just use “$this->load->model(‘my_model’);” and use its functions, but how to create a factory object, and make it return the concrete model you need, which you use through an interface (abstract class)?

Is there any chance to achieve this?

Thanks to all of you people.

Comment: Just because you're using Codeigniter doesn't mean you're bound to its (few) conventions. Are you able to figure this out with vanilla PHP? What specific issues did you run into trying to implement this in Codeigniter?

Comment: I was trying not to break the model calling way that CodeIgniter provides. It doesn't make much sense to use a framework and not stay with its wat of doing things. That's why I was trying to figure out if I could use the pattern without just getting rid of models from a MVC framework.

Comment: Well CI is the type of framework that gets out of your way and lets you do things the way you want, that's why I like it. I don't like only having a single instance of every class/library/model and being forced to have the constructor accept only a "config" array. If this were another more robust framework, I might agree that it's best to stick to the predetermined conventions. I still ask - what specific trouble did you have so far?

Comment: The problem I have is that the only way CI provides to load a model is by calling "this->load->model('my_model')" and then you just have to call "this->my_model->my_function()", and I don't know how to load the interface model, and then assign to that interface a concrete object that is returned by a factory. Or should I just use it like pure OO PHP and forget about the "load->model"?

Comment: If I saw some example code I could give better advice, despite my unfamiliarity with the "abstract factory pattern". I'm sure you can do it both ways, CI models themselves *are* just PHP classes after all, and they don't have to extend `CI_Model` (or anything). When you say "load" the interface, is this something that you can't handle with an `include`? I'm just not sure what the specific problem is.

Comment: I think the problem is just a syntax one. As I'm reading right now, the "load->model" syntax is a way CI has to load PHP classes, instead of the pure PHP way, but they can be perfectly interchangeable. I if make it work i'll post the code here :)

Answer (score 1):

Hm- so you want to be able to switch between different db implementations. Wouldn't the adapter pattern be better suited for this? You would just have to create a new model that wraps the new db and call that one. I thought abstract factory was just for creating a set of related/dependent objects without exposing their concrete classes. If that's what you want to do, then I think you can create a model that acts as a factory, and then other models that extend an abstract class model (I've never tried this but I figure you can try to load it within a class to extend it). That way when you load the factory, you can call one of the methods and its method will load the right implementation for you(with the loading happening in the method of your factory).